# Redimensionar imagens com Print.Window

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma *function* que tira print de um imagem para poder imprimir a mesma.
Porém eu gostaria de saber se tem como mudar a posição desta imagem na hora que entra no método.

No momento a *function* abre assim a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de redimensionar a imagem em 90º à direita para poder pegar a folha (formato A4), isso é possível ?

Segue código:

```
function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
           var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'left=10,top=10,width=740,height=600');

            printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.focus();
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor no CSS da sua página vc pode fazer um estilo para mudar a orientação da folha apenas na hora da impressão dessa forma.

```
@page {
  size: A4 landscape;
}
```

Talvez vc tenha que adaptar seu JS para chamar esse css caso vc não use css no projeto.

Veja um exemplo prático:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    width: 90%;
}
@page {
  size: landscape;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src='http://unsplash.it/600/280' style="width: 100%;" alt="">
</div>
```

Com esse exemplo acima obtive esses resultados

## COM @page size: landscape

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## SEM @page size

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem uma documentação da Mozilla sobre o `@page` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size